# Pjsip echo cancellation

Tags: android, sip, voip, pjsip

I need to activate the echo cancelation algorithm and I try to add 
[#define PJMEDIA_HAS_SPEEX_AEC   1](http://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/group__PJMEDIA__CONFIG.htm#ga28ceda7724d9da106c3bf52573ba5d00)
 in the **config_site.h** but then I realise that this is the default behaviour of PJSIP. But I'm listening a lot of echo during a call.

Can someone tell me what variable should I set to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WebRTC - implementation available in trunk, earlier used e.g. by csipsimple.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably speex does not work well in your scenario. Take a look at PJSIP's [datasheet](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/PJSIP-Datasheet) . Multiple echo cancellation options are available.